# Process mongodump gzip archive in python

Tags: python, gzip, tar, mongodump, tarfile

I am using python to export some collections from the database, by running mongodump command.
An example command is something like this

```
run(f'{to_debug()}mongodump --uri="{uri}" -c "projects" --query=\'{project_query}\' --gzip '
        f'--archive="{file_parts[0]}.projects{file_parts[1]}"')
```

As you can see, the result is beeing archived and gzipped.

The export works ok, and if I want to import afterwards the resulted archives, everything it’s ok.

The problem is that now I need to process a little bit the data from within the archive, so I would like to access the archive contents inside python and take some information from there.

Until now, I tried tarfile module from python but it doesn’t work, basically I cannot even open the archive - the errors that I am receivieng are invalid header or not a gzip file …
Does anyone from here has some experience or encountered this use case ? Any suggestions will be welcomed :)

Thank you

Comment: According to [this](https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/archiving-and-compression-in-mongodb-tools), it is using it's own homegrown format -- not tar.

Comment: Yes, that's a good article, apparently I cannot use it as I want in my use case :| thx anyway @MarkAdler

Comment: The point is tarfile _won't work_. It's not a tar.gz file.